# multiple datasource configuration and use in sping boot 2 using hikari

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

I have configured two Postgres database with spring boot but spring always pics the primary database and ignore the secondary, any help will be appreciated.

below is mine configuration

application.properties

```
#datasource 1
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
    spring.datasource.username=user1
    spring.datasource.password=user1

#data source 2    
    spring.datasource2.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
    spring.datasource2.username=user2
    spring.datasource2.password=user2
```

configuration for data source 1 is below I have multiple repository and entities in data source 1 and this is my primary data source.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"pkg.user_service.repository","pkg.master.repository","pkg.Wallet.repository","pkg.security.repositories",
                "pkg.product_service.repository","pkg.OMS.repository","pkg.LMS.repository","pkg.payment.repository"}
)    
public class DataSource1_config {  

 @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }



      @Primary
        @Bean(name = "primaryEntityManager")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                        .dataSource(dataSource(null))
                       .packages("pkg") 
                        .persistenceUnit("primaryPU")
                        .build();
        }

      @Primary
        @Bean(name = "primaryTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }


}
```

Configuration for datsource2 is below there is single repository and entity in data source 2.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondTransactionManager",             
        basePackages = {"device_info.repository"}
)

public class DataSource2_config {   

    @Bean 
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource2")
     public HikariDataSource secondSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }


        @Bean(name = "secondEntityManager")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                        .dataSource(secondSource(null))
                        .packages(User_Device_Info.class) 
                        .persistenceUnit("secondPU")
                        .build();
        }



        @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a project that I can create multiple dataSources with your specific changeSets, so if you need to add another dataSource, it would just change your application.yml, no longer needing to change the code.

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.liquibase", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

    private LiquibaseProperties properties;
    private DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("tenantRoutingDataSource")
    public MultiTenantDataSourceSpringLiquibase liquibaseMultiTenancy(Map<Object, Object> dataSources,
                                                                      @Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        // to run changeSets of the liquibase asynchronous
        MultiTenantDataSourceSpringLiquibase liquibase = new MultiTenantDataSourceSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor);
        dataSources.forEach((tenant, dataSource) -> liquibase.addDataSource((String) tenant, (DataSource) dataSource));
        dataSourceProperties.getDataSources().forEach(dbProperty -> {
            if (dbProperty.getLiquibase() != null) {
                liquibase.addLiquibaseProperties(dbProperty.getTenantId(), dbProperty.getLiquibase());
            }
        });

        liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
        liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
        return liquibase;
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  dataSources:
    - tenantId: db1
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      liquibase:
        enabled: true
        default-schema: public
        change-log: classpath:db/master/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    - tenantId: db2
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    - tenantId: db3
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db3
      username: postgres
      password: 123456
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

See the code complete: https://github.com/dijalmasilva/spring-boot-multitenancy-datasource-liquibase